# Confusing when publish my React Native Application to google play

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, google-developers-console, react-fullstack

After android application expo building done and got APK/BUNDLE file ready to publish and access to google console and begin to fill all the forms stages one by one but when i got finish i face the open & closed & internal tests, for the first moment i didn't understand what these tests for.

After reading all the instructions i understad that somebody have to test my application, but who?

I saw that each one (open, closed, internal test) gives me a url.
i think this url is my application in google play but not for public just to give testers access to check my app.

Noteworthy the app got a temporary name.

I have give myself as a tester and app got installed by google play url ( talked above) on my phone, everything works fine but i dont know how to give pass to the tests.

thank you

After testing my app, every thing work very well, but still writen beside by app on the dashboard it is a draft and still writen not checked ?????

i get lost, what to do ?? maybe to wait for google testers ?? or maybe i forget something.??

please help....!!!!!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is no code for the issue, it is just an logistic matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open & closed & internal just for testing your app before it is available to all users. Testers can test your app if any bug happens while testing you have to upload a new app with resolved bugs. And if anything goes right you can directly upload it to production.

Draft in dashboard that means you have upload apk and doesn't rollout it to production.

Comment: thank you very much, after few days of google checking my app i got updated by google console about the issue.